# Column Validation Formula in a Single Line of Text Column

Tags: 2013

We use a custom list to log keys signed out from our office.  One of the columns is a Single Line of Text column titled 'Signed Out To'.  In this column we enter the name of the person receiving the key, and the company they work for.  However, we would like to enforce a certain type of input i.e. FIRSTNAME SURNAME (COMPANY NAME) to ensure uniformity of entries.

Can the column validation function enforce this, and if so what would be the formula?!

Comment: If an answer was helpful could you remove your question from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 1):

You could do a partial check, check if there's a ( and a ) in the name - that's probably going to be the most 'forgotten' part of your structure. You can't really check to see if where they are is correct, but it's a start

```
=AND(NOT(ISERR(Search("(", [Signed Out To]))),
     NOT(ISERR(Search(")", [Signed Out To]))))
```

You could also AND in another test to see if ) is the last character of the field, that would narrow it down as well. And make sure the description of the field includes instructions to the proper formatting of the field, so you can point to that when they don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

Start with a simple Validation Formula and extend it from there.

It is going to be very specific for your Use Case so there is no ready made Formula

Its best to create the Formula in Excel first so you can test/develop live without the SharePoint reload hassle.
Once it works fine on your $A$1 Excel field, rename teh Cell reference to the SharePoint Column name and you can paste the Formula in a validation rule.

Most basic functions are the same:

http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List